# React/Enzyme testing - retrieving the state after simulated events (async or sync?)

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have started learning React/Enzyme and I have a question about the behavior of setState() in tests.

I understand that setState() can be sometimes async for performance reasons. 
However I've seen several examples like the following:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={`clicks-${count}`}>
          {count} clicks
        </div>
        <a href="url" onClick={() => { this.setState({ count: count + 1 }); }}>
          Increment
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
expect(wrapper.state().count).to.equal(1);
```

As you can see, calling `simulate('click')` has the effect of executing `this.setState({ count: count + 1 })`. Right after this, the state is being retrieved and then used to make a comparison.

I have tested similar examples and they seem to work, but isn't it possible for the `setState()` to be async and then the `wrapper.state()` call from the comparison to not give  the desired results?

I don't know, maybe wrapper.state() is async, but I don't think so.

I have also read the following discussion:[setState calls within simulate events (async or not?)](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1054.)

The recommended solution is to make every event handler return a promise, but I'm not sure about this, I haven't seen this method be applied in any of the examples I've looked into. Even the examples from the Enzyme website don't implement this solution.

So my question is whether or not `wrapper.state()` is indeed async and if so, what is the appropriate method for testing such code?

Thanks!